# Prevent to call serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have create serializer called `user serailizer`

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :email, :display_name
end
```

On call of

```
render json: User.all, status: 200
```

This will return

```
[{id:1, email: test@gmail.com, display_name: 'test'},{id:2, email: test1@gmail.com, display_name: 'test1'}]
```

And my user table have many more attributes

Here I dont want to render serializer attribute, want to render user table all attributes without change in serializer
In short I want to prevent to call serializer on every render json, I want to render serializer attributes when I want>

I also tried with

```
render json: User.all, serializer: nil, status: 200
```

But there is no luck

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error showing?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon when I am calling `serializer: nil` it was not showing any error, it still calling serializer

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do, why you have a UserSerializer that you don't want to use, why you don't make a SpecialCaseUserSerializer, why you want to render every single user and every single database column... but this might be what you want:

`render json: User.all.to_json, status: :ok`

If that doesn't do what you want, you'll need to share some more information such as the version you're on, what you've tried, any error messages you've gotten, and details / examples of what it is you want to do, as opposed to how what you're doing isn't working.